# Can't apply css filters to context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a filter to my image that is uploaded from my computer, but no filters are applied. I write ctx.filter = "contrast(1.6)" to apply filters, but it doesn't work. Everything else works perfectly.

I think it might be a compatibility issue. However, I am not quite sure. I use Safari as my browser. If it is a problem with Safari is it any way I can make it work with Safari?

Here is the code:

```js
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img;

function handleImage(e){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      var ratio = this.height / this.width;
      canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
      ctx.filter = "contrast(1.6)"
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Safari doesn't support filters apparently, but you also need a percentage value, like `canvas(50%)`. Note that increasing the contrast beyond 100% seems to not be possible. However there are other ways to do that (pixel manipulation: getImageData(), change the array of RGBA values, then putImageData()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.filter` does not work in safari

you can use this library for work in safari

https://github.com/davidenke/context-filter-polyfill

or

http://ocanvas.org/

Comment: Will these libraries make the code automatically be compatible for Safari as well, or do I have to write different code for Safari?

Comment: @Emil yes first link code automatically be compatible with Safari

Answer (score 0):

ctx.filter does not support in safari

[image]

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter